# Accessing jekyll collection attributes from markdown

Tags: collections, attributes, jekyll, liquid

I have a set of collections representing courses I teach. Each of them has some unique attributes associated with that course.  For example:

```
# Collections, which are CS courses for me
collections:  
  cs1:  
    output: true  
    title:  "CS1"  
    permalink: /teaching/cs1/:path/  
    TAemail: "cs1@school.edu"  

  cs2:
    output: true  
    title:  "CS2"  
    permalink: /teaching/cs2/:path/  
    TAemail: "cs2@school.edu"  
   ...
```

In each collection, there is a `Logistics.md` file that should present the email address for that course.  For example, if the course was cs2 what I want to use is:

```
[Teaching team email](mailto:{{ site.cs2.TAemail }}) ...
```

However, this doesn't work.  If I put the `TAemail` name in the `Logistics.md` file within the collection, and do some sort of lookup for it like:

```
{% for file in site.cs2 %}
  {% if file.type == 'Info' %}
      {% if file.subtype == 'Logistics' %}
| | email: | [ Team ](mailto: {{ file.TAemail }}) |  
      {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

it works fine.  This seems awkward and not very jekyll-like.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean `[Teaching team email](mailto: {{site.cs2.TAemail}})`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, transcription error.  I will correct the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{{ site.cs2.TAemail }}` doesn't work because `site.cs2` is an array with the items of the collection, so you can't access the metadata you specified, as it is not a property of the array.

The way to access collection metadata, is via `site.collections`.

e.g.

```
{% assign cs_collection = site.collections | where: "label", "cs1" | first %}
Send e-mail to: {{ cs_collection.TAemail }}
```

---

BTW, each item of the collection contains a property called `collection`, with the name of the collection that it belongs to, so you can dynamically query the collection based on the item, without having to hard-code the collection name in the where filter.

e.g.

```
{% for item in site.cs1 %}
  {% assign this_collection = item.collection %}

  {% assign cs_collection = site.collections | where: "label", this_collection | first %}
  Send e-mail to: {{ cs_collection.TAemail }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: WOW!  The first answer works great!  The second one is cool, but I ended up with eight lines of "Send e-mail to: ...", one for each of the attribute lines in the collection definition.  Many, many thanks!  I've been fighting with this for many hours.  ccp

Comment: @user1055983 The second answer was just an example for you to adapt, if you were rendering the items in the collection, and wanted to display the e-mail associated with the collection

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation, and MANY thanks for your answers!  This has been a HUGE time sink for me.